# Define test variables in QUnit setup

Tags: javascript, scope, qunit

I realized that the `QUnit.module` provides setup and teardown callbacks surrounding each tests.

```
QUnit.module("unrelated test", {
    setup: function() {
        var usedAcrossTests = "hello";
    }
});
QUnit.test("some test", function(assert) {
    assert.deepEqual(usedAcrossTests, "hello", "uh oh");
});
QUnit.test("another test", function(assert) {
    assert.deepEqual(usedAcrossTests.length, 5, "uh oh");
});
```

As seen in `setup`, I want to declare a variable to use across the following `QUnit.test`s. However, since the variable only has function scope, the two tests fail, saying `usedAcrossTests is undefined`.

I could remove the `var` declaration, but then that would pollute the global scope. Especially if I will have multiple modules, I'd rather not be declaring test-specific variables as global.

Is there a way to specify, in `setup` a variable to be used in the tests within the module, without polluting the global scope?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just realized that it is more simpler than my previous answer.
Just add all properties that you want to access in all other test of modules in current object.

```
QUnit.module("unrelated test", {
    setup: function() {
        this.usedAcrossTests = "hello"; // add it to current context 'this'
    }
});
```

And then in each test where you wish to use this.

```
QUnit.test("some test", function(assert) {
    assert.deepEqual(this.usedAcrossTests, "hello", "uh oh");
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This advice is still helpful in 2019 working with QUnit 2.x (see https://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/). We need to be careful, however, in a complex set of tests, with nested modules. The 'this' context in the nested module is not the 'this' context of the parent module, so you need to create a variable in the parent module like 'self' (or 'that' or whatever) and assign the parent 'this' context to it. The nested module then has access to the parent context via the variable 'self'.